# c++ ui automation - click a button programmatically

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ui-automation, sendmessage

I need to click on the "I Agree" button in the below code programmatically, could you please help? is this possible to use SendMessage(hButton, BM_CLICK, 0, 0); ?

```
typedef HRESULT STDAPICALLTYPE AcquireDeveloperLicense(
    _In_opt_ HWND     hwndParent,
    _Out_    FILETIME *pExpiration
    );
HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary(TEXT("WSClient.dll"));
AcquireDeveloperLicense *acquire_license = (AcquireDeveloperLicense*)GetProcAddress(hDll, "AcquireDeveloperLicense");
FILETIME pExpiration = {};
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
HRESULT result = acquire_license(hwnd, &pExpiration);
```

Comment: What are you going to use this for ?

Comment: If you get the HWND of the button on the license dialog, then yes, you can send `BM_CLICK` to it. You can call `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT)` or `SetWinEventHook()` before calling `AcquireDeveloperLicense()` to hook into the dialog's creation and get its HWND, then use `FindWindow/Ex()` or `EnumChildWindows()` to find the button HWND